# How to merge more than one profile type within registration page?

Tags: 7, users

So I am using [profile2](http://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module to create different types of user profiles

for example

- personal information profile
- contact information profile
- team profile - team role
- member profile  - member role

contact information profile is a common profile (fields) between team user and member user

I created a registration page for each role using [profile2 registration path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module, in this module I can only create one registration path for each profile which will combine Drupal account fields with profile2 profile fields.

Current registration pages as follow:

- team profile registration page
- member profile registration page

Now I want to include/merge contact information profile fields with team and member profiles in the registration page without creating redundant fields for each profile.

Any helpful ideas

Answer (score 0):

If you create fields for one profile, you can also use the same fields for another profile type.

When making the fields for the second type, rather than make new ones use the "Already Existing" Field to select the already made fields from a drop-down list.

This way both roles will fill in the same Contact Information since they both used the same fields for the task.

Comment: this solution will only solve part of my issue. profile2 module allow you to have different pages for each profile and I want to separate team profile from contact profile in edit and view mode